# What does "a lesser human being" mean?

Tags: meaning

I want to understand what the speaker meant in this sentence.

> You’re a lesser human being.

Actually I've checked with this [site](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/a-lesser-man-woman-person) but I don't really understand that meant.
Could anyone give me a further explanation?

Comment: The person in question was considered to be in some way inferior to the speaker, or to humanity in general. Your link defines it as 'morally inferior', but depending on context it might have other meanings.

Comment: It would be rude if not used in the sense 'than you could/should be // could have been if you'd made braver/more selfless choices.'

Comment: The 'subhuman' metaphor is seen in 'Man up!', 'He's not the man he used to be', 'He's a _real_ man!